# TikZ image with hyperlinks --> GIF/PNG image + HTML image map

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, hyperref, links, gif

I have a (complex) TikZ-based figure with hyperlinks. Now I need a web version of this figure that preserves all hyperlinks. Converting the PDF to GIF or PNG is trivial, but for the hyperlinks I additionally need a corresponding [HTML image map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map).

So what are the possible/preferable conversion routes from LaTeX -> GIF/PNG (with image map)?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
        \node[name=Q, draw=red!80, top color=red!60, bottom color=red!20, font=\Huge] 
            {\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115400}{Question at tex.se}};
  \node[name=A1, draw=blue!80, top color=blue!60, bottom color=blue!20, font=\Huge, below of=Q]
            {\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115518/3751}{Answer by Yori}};
  \draw[->] (Q) -- (A1);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Result as GIF (no image map, yet):

[image]

Comment: AFAIK only SVG and Flash allow for mouse sensitive regions.

Comment: @AlexG: Oh, I always considered this to be a GIF feature. What I have just learned is that I am actually looking for a LaTeX --> GIF/PNG **+ image map** converter. I have edited the question and its title.

Comment: @AlexG, Daniel: AFAIK mouse sensitive regions / image maps is an HTML feature, which works with any image type.

Comment: @Daniel: Your MWE should be a little more complex. At the moment you only generate one hyperlinked node which fills 100% of the image. This example clearly doesn't need image maps. You should at least have two nodes with some empty space between them.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Good point, now as I also got the first answer, the second node was obvious :-)

Comment: SVG natively supports links; is there a particular reason you want a (lossy) pixel graphic?

Comment: @Raphael: Hm... good point. Probably because I am not so sure about SVG support in all those browsers around.

Comment: @Daniel Apparently, [support is well in current browsers](http://caniuse.com/svg). Whether this is sufficient for your purposes depends on your target group, and whether they want something from you or you from them, I guess.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this can be done with pgfmath, assuming that you have exactly one tikzpicture in your LaTeX file, and nothing else. Note that if the document uses the document class `standalone`, then there are some ways for determining the size of the output bitmap (e.g., GIF or PNG) in advance.

***See http://www.colatex.net/scrap/imagemap/map.html for a live view of what the code below does.*** (This page uses a jQuery plugin called jQuery.maphilight to visualizes the link regions. For some mysterious reason, this plugin is hosted on one of my favorite movie  directors' website: http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/)

---

To generate the image map, I made a TiKZ library `imagemap`. 
In order to generate an image map file, the basic idea is to calculate for each link (i.e., node with href attribute) the coordinates of the relevant shape in the tikzpicture, relative to the current bounding box. To obtain the coordinates measured in pixels for the image map, we normalize these coordinates to lie within the interval [0, 1], and then multiply by the dimensions of the target bitmap.

The code for this library is the file `tikzlibraryimagemap.code.tex`:

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xstring}
\RequirePackage{newfile}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% Register PGF keys
% ------------------------------------------------------------------
\tikzset{image map/.style={
    execute at begin picture={\gdef\write@areas{}},
    execute at end picture={\write@image@map},
    every node/.style={
         execute at begin node=\stepcounter{im@nodes},
         execute at end node=\im@register@node, 
         alias=im@node@\arabic{im@nodes}}
}}

\def\im@density{auto}
\def\im@width{auto}
\def\im@height{auto}
\def\im@mapfilename{\jobname.html}
\def\im@mapname{image-map}
\def\im@bitmap{\jobname.png}
\def\im@curhref{}
\def\im@curalt{}
\def\im@curtitle{}
\def\im@curtarget{}

\pgfkeys{tikz/.cd, 
   image map file/.store in=\im@mapfilename,
   image map file/.initial=\jobname.html,
   image map bitmap/.store in=\im@bitmap,
   image map bitmap/.initial=\jobname.png,
   image map width/.store in=\im@density,
   image map width/.initial=auto,
   image map width/.store in=\im@width,
   image map width/.initial=auto,
   image map height/.store in=\im@height,
   image map height/.initial=auto,
   image map name/.store in=\im@mapname,
   image map name/.initial=image-map,
   alt/.initial={},
   alt/.store in=\im@curalt,
   title/.initial={},
   title/.store in=\im@curtitle,
   target/.initial={},
   target/.store in=\im@curtarget,
   href/.initial={},
   href/.store in=\im@curhref}


% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% Define a \hashchar command which is just the hash character (#)
% This is required for writing a hash character to file.
% ------------------------------------------------------------------
\begingroup
\catcode`\#=12
\gdef\hashchar{#}%
\endgroup


% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% Code for registering nodes as potential click area
% ------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcounter{im@nodes}

% Register the current node as a potential area
\def\im@register@node{%
  \ifdefempty{\im@curhref}{}{%
    \global\edef\im@attr{href="\im@curhref"}%
    \ifdefempty{\im@curalt}{}{%
       \global\edef\im@attr{\im@attr\space alt="\im@curalt"}%
    }%
    \ifdefempty{\im@curtarget}{}{%
       \global\edef\im@attr{\im@attr\space target="\im@curtarget"}%
    }%
    \ifdefempty{\im@curtitle}{}{%
       \global\edef\im@attr{\im@attr\space title="\im@curtitle"}%
    }%
    %
    % Define the command \im@shape@writer, depending on the value of \tikz@shape
    \let\im@shape@writer\@empty%
    \edef\im@tikz@shape{{\tikz@shape}}%
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\im@tikz@shape{circle}{%
        \def\im@shape@writer{write@ellipse@area}%
    }{}%
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\im@tikz@shape{ellipse}{%
        \def\im@shape@writer{write@ellipse@area}%
    }{}%
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\im@tikz@shape{rectangle}{%
        \def\im@shape@writer{write@rectangle@area}%
    }{}%
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\im@tikz@shape{diamond}{%
        \def\im@shape@writer{write@diamond@area}%
    }{}%
    %
    % If the command \im@add@shape was not defined, the shape is not supported.
    \ifdefempty{\im@shape@writer}{%
       \errmessage{Shape "\tikz@shape" is not supported by image map.}
    }{%
       \edef\im@tmp{\noexpand\im@add@shape{\im@shape@writer}{im@node@\arabic{im@nodes}}{\im@attr}}%
       \im@tmp%
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand\im@add@shape[3]{%
   \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\write@areas\expandafter{\write@areas \csname #1\endcsname{#2}{#3}}%
}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% Code for writing the HTML output
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

% Writes the image map to file
\def\write@image@map{
   \begingroup

   % Determine current bounding box  
   \path (current bounding box.north west);
   \pgfgetlastxy{\bbxnw}{\bbynw}
   \path (current bounding box.south east);
   \pgfgetlastxy{\bbxse}{\bbyse}

   % Determine image width and height if not set manually
   \ifstandalone%
      \IfStrEq{\sa@convert@size}{}{}{%
         \IfSubStr{\sa@convert@size}{x}{%
            \StrBefore{\sa@convert@size}{x}[\im@width@tmp]%
            \StrBehind{\sa@convert@size}{x}[\im@height@tmp]%
            \gdef\im@width{\im@width@tmp}%
            % The standalone class seems to ignore the height, so 
            % we'll do the same:
%            \gdef\im@height{\im@height@tmp}%   
         }{%
            \gdef\im@width{\sa@convert@size}%
            \gdef\im@height{auto}%
         }%
      }%
   \fi


   \IfStrEq{\im@width}{auto}{%
      \IfStrEq{\im@height}{auto}{%
          % Determine density (in pts per inch) if set to auto
          \IfStrEq{\im@density}{auto}{%
             \ifstandalone%
                \gdef\im@density{\sa@convert@density}%
             \else%
                \gdef\im@density{72}%
             \fi%
          }{}%
         \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\im@width@tmp}{round((\bbxse-\bbxnw)/72.27*\im@density)}%
         \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\im@height@tmp}{round((\bbynw-\bbyse)/72.27*\im@density)}%
         \gdef\im@width{\im@width@tmp}%
         \gdef\im@height{\im@height@tmp}%
      }{%
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\im@width@tmp}{round(\im@height/(\bbynw-\bbyse)*(\bbxse-\bbxnw))}%
       \gdef\im@width{\im@width@tmp}%
      }%
   }{%
     \IfStrEq{\im@height}{auto}{%
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\im@height@tmp}{round(\im@width/(\bbxnw-\bbxse)*(\bbyse-\bbynw))}%
       \gdef\im@height{\im@height@tmp}%
     }
   }

   % Write output
   \newoutputstream{mapfile}%
   \openoutputfile{\im@mapfilename}{mapfile}%
   \addtostream{mapfile}{<img src="\im@bitmap" usemap="\hashchar\im@mapname" width="\im@width" height="\im@height">}
   \addtostream{mapfile}{<map name="\im@mapname">}
   \write@areas
   \addtostream{mapfile}{</map>}
   \addtostream{mapfile}{</img>}
   \closeoutputstream{mapfile}

   \endgroup
}

% Transformation functions
\newcommand\im@transformx[2]{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{#1}{round(((#2)-\bbxnw)/(\bbxse-\bbxnw)*\im@width)}
}

\newcommand\im@transformy[2]{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{#1}{round(((#2)-\bbynw)/(\bbyse-\bbynw)*\im@height)}
}

% Writes a rectangular area to the image map. 
\newcommand\write@rectangle@area[2]{
  % Determine boundary of the shape
  \path (#1.north west);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\shxnw}{\shynw}
  \path (#1.south east);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\shxse}{\shyse}

  % Calculate boundary of shape in pixel units
  \im@transformx{\xnw}{\shxnw}
  \im@transformy{\ynw}{\shynw}
  \im@transformx{\xse}{\shxse}
  \im@transformy{\yse}{\shyse}

  % Write to the map file
  \addtostream{mapfile}{<area shape="rect" coords="\xnw,\ynw,\xse,\yse" #2>}
}


% Writes a ellipse-shaped area to the image map. 
\newcommand\write@ellipse@area[2]{
  % Determine boundary of the shape. Note that the 
  % north west and south east anchors are actually ON the circle.
  % Hence, the factor sqrt(2) in the calculations below.
  \path (#1.north west);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\shxnw}{\shynw}
  \path (#1.south east);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\shxse}{\shyse}

  % Calculate ellipse parameters in pixel units
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xctr}{0.5*\shxnw+0.5*\shxse}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\yctr}{0.5*\shynw+0.5*\shyse}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\radx}{\shxse-\shxnw)/sqrt(2)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rady}{\shyse-\shynw)/sqrt(2)}

  % Construct list of coordinates on the circle
  \def\im@coords{}
  \foreach [count=\i] \angle in {0, 18, ..., 360} {
     \im@transformx{\x}{round(\xctr+sin(\angle)*\radx)}
     \im@transformy{\y}{round(\yctr+cos(\angle)*\rady)}
     \ifnum\i>1     
        \global\edef\im@coords{\im@coords,}
     \fi
     \global\edef\im@coords{\im@coords\x,\y}
  }

  % Write to the map file
  \addtostream{mapfile}{<area shape="poly" coords="\im@coords" #2>}
}

% Writes a diamond-shaped to the image map. 
\newcommand\write@diamond@area[2]{
  \def\im@coords{}
  \foreach [count=\i] \anchor in {north, east, south, west} {
     \path (#1.\anchor);
     \pgfgetlastxy{\shx}{\shy}
     \im@transformx{\x}{\shx}
     \im@transformy{\y}{\shy}
     \ifnum\i>1     
        \global\edef\im@coords{\im@coords,}
     \fi
     \global\edef\im@coords{\im@coords\x,\y}
  }

  % Write to the map file
  \addtostream{mapfile}{<area shape="poly" coords="\im@coords" #2>}
}
```

(I have no idea whether using `\RequirePackage` inside a TiKZ library is considered good practice, but it works)

---

***Example usage:***
The following (rather straightforward) document `map.tex` uses the TiKZ library to generate an image map:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=100}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,imagemap}

\begin{document}
    % open map file map.txt, assuming the bitmap will have dimension 300x100
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=100pt, 
            image map, 
            image map file=map.html,
            image map bitmap=map.png]
        \node (A) [circle, draw, top color=red!60, bottom color=red!20, font=\Huge,
                   href=http://tex.stackexchange.com/] 
            {tex.se};

        \node [rectangle, draw, top color=green!60, bottom color=green!20, font=\Huge,below of=A,
                   href=http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115400] 
            {Question at tex.se};

        \node (B) [ellipse, draw, top color=blue!60, bottom color=blue!20, font=\Huge,right of=A,xshift=80pt,
                   href=https://www.google.com, alt=Google search] 
            {Google search};

        \node [diamond, draw, top color=yellow!60, bottom color=yellow!20, font=\Huge,below of=B,
                   href=http://news.bbc.co.uk, target=_new] 
            {BBC news};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

After compiling this document using `--shell-escape` (so that the PDF file gets converted to a PNG file), I get the following 521x278 PNG file:

[image]

And a corresponding HTML file `map.html` containing the image map:

```
<img src="map.png" usemap="#image-map" width="521" height="278">
<map name="image-map">
<area shape="poly" coords="130,92,145,89,159,81,170,69,175,54,175,38,170,23,159,11,145,3,130,0,114,3,100,11,90,23,84,38,84,54,90,69,100,81,114,89,130,92" href="http://tex.stackexchange.com/">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,164,259,204" href="http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115400">
<area shape="poly" coords="379,74,427,73,470,68,502,60,519,51,519,41,502,32,470,24,427,19,379,18,330,19,288,24,256,32,239,41,239,51,256,60,288,68,330,73,379,74" href="https://www.google.com" alt="Google search">
<area shape="poly" coords="379,90,473,184,379,278,285,184" href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_new">
</map>
</img>
```

And this works! You can view the live result at http://www.colatex.net/scrap/imagemap/map.html.

---

***Remarks***

- Rectangular, circular, elliptical, and diamond-shaped link areas are supported.
- Circular and elliptical areas are approximated by polygons because ellipses are not supported by HTML areas. (Note that circles might turn into ellipses when the aspect ratio is not 1.)
- The dimensions given in `map.html` are calculated using the bounding box of the unique TiKZ picture in `map.tex`, and the density as given by the options in the `standalone` document style. The height and/or width can be overridden by adding the options `image map width=` and/or `image map height=` in the TiKZ environment (the values should be number of pixels without units, e.g., `image map width=100`). If only one of the width/height is given, then the other one is calculated based on the aspect ratio of the TiKZ picture.
- Currently, the library assumes that the TiKZ picture is ***the only*** object in the output PNG (so no surrounding text is allowed -- the calculations will get messed up).
- You can add `alt`, `target`, and `title` attributes to the areas if necessary. See the example above.

Comment: Awesome! IIRC, HTML image maps allow arbitrary point sets. So, in principle, it should be possible to support non-rectangle shapes; I have no idea how (well) this would work for non-straight edges, though. (And how hard it would be to code, this is clearly beyond my own skills.)

Comment: @Daniel : True, once w have the relevant coordinates/measurements from TiKZ, I know how to proceed. But I don't even know how to detect whether a node is a circle, a rectangle, or a polygonal node. Any ideas?

Comment: @Daniel: Well the shape name is not the problem. I used `\tikz@shape` first, but as per your suggestion, I aliased it. The problem is getting the coordinates of the path (rectangle/circle/polygon) drawn around the node.

Comment: Bounty well deserved :-)

Comment: @Daniel: Just did so. I will clean up the code as well and see if I can submit this code to CRAN. BTW I did not implement your `title` suggestion, as I do not think it is offical HTML, is it?

Comment: AFAIK `title` is an official (X)HTML _universal attribute_, that is, it can appear on any element (and, thus, may not be directly listed in the docs regarding `map` and `area`.) Submitting to CTAN is a good idea!