# getmap: How to create simple, debunked maps?

Tags: getmap

I read https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183138/46023 
and I ask myself, whether it is possible to get a 'debunked' map like this

[image]

but maybe with country-names, by using the getmap-package:

[image]

Maybe through color reversal or something?

Note:  *In Google gm or gsv mode it does nothing for me, in no (manual) example. There's something in the manual about request restrictions, maybe it has something to do with it. 

But the osm-mode works.*

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell : yes }
\documentclass[varwidth, margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor}
\usepackage[overwrite=true]{getmap}
\begin{document}
\getmap[
file=theworld,
%mode=osm, % Default
%type=map, % Default
%xsize=900, % ?
%ysize=400, % ?
%scale=2, % ?
zoom=3, % ?
]{World}
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{theworld}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess this is more a question about parameters to the various mapping APIs (for Google you can specify a colored overlay on a map for example) and not about the LaTeX-aspects of using the package, so it's not really on-topic on TeX.SE I think.

Comment: A not very beautiful solution using only PGF/Ti*k*Z is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593495/162128).

Comment: @vipa I think your solution is quite nice actually :) such an approach (storing a shape path for a country as a list of numbers) is probably also how real mapping libraries work.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that svg-files can only be found  (on wikipedia)  in special cases, for example in the example here. For example, if only a city or a district is to be set in the "debunked" style, this method would not work. In principle, it would be good if one could convert any OpenStreetMap map into this desired style.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about API calls and not about LaTeX.